# How to add Telerik.WinControls assembly to global assembly cache in windows 2008 servser R2

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, telerik

Hello i build some application in wcf with winForms, when i run standart(vs 2012) element on form(button,labes...) all work fine,but when i add telerik components like Scheduler i getting error that say that i need to instal telerik.Scheduler to global assembly cache first, but i have this dll all ready.

Here the image of error and properties of dll:

[image]

On my local pc all works fine.

I am working on **vs2012 frame 4 win7-64** and i am runnig this apllication on **windows 2008 server R2**.

Can any one help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem like this:

1:Clean project and delete old files from Degub/bin.

2:Make sure all telerik dll's have the same version(end's .20 or .40)  **!!IMPORTANT!!**.

3:In Telerik dll's click properties, and then make Copy Local = true  **!!IMPORTANT!!**.

4:Rebuild the project.

After all this steps all start to work.